# Select Custom AutoHotKey Tray Icon from .ico file

Tags: icons, autohotkey, .ico

I have a functioning AHK script, and I want to assign a custom icon to it in the toolbar, I have a .ico file that I created that has the icon that i want to use. I can use the default (first) page in the .ico file just fine, but I need to use the second one. How do I do this?
This is the troublesome line of code

```
Menu, Tray, Icon, \\volvo\users\pleavitt\Documents\Paul\Interface\Custom Icons\T-CheckIcon.ico,1,1
```

If I change the first "1" at the end of the code to a "2" it throws an error, but from [this](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Menu.htm) webpage I thought that that is what I was supposed to do.

In conclusion, I want to be able to select a page from the .ico file to use as the tray icon for my AHK script.
thanks!
Paul

Comment: Please use the latest autohotkey version + docs here: http://ahkscript.org/

Answer (score 3):

## Menu

Documentation: http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Menu.htm

---

`Menu, Tray, FileName [, IconNumber, IconWidth]`
`IconNumber` and `IconWidth` are optional.
I am unsure that it supports Files on a network, i.e. `\\path\to\file.ico`.

Try copying it to the script's directory, and use the relative path like so :
`Menu, Tray, Icon, %A_ScriptDir%\T-CheckIcon.ico`

*NB:* Be sure to use the latest version of AutoHotkey.